# Email Task in Informatica

Tags: email, informatica

Is there a way of sending a text version of your changes to a mapping on an email task? I have mapping that would make approximately 10 changes to a table. As this mapping finishes, I want to use the email task to send the recipient a list of changes that were made.

Is that possible? (If not, is the next best solution outputting these changes to a .txt or flat file, and sending that to the recipient?) Either way, can someone provide detailed instructions on how to accomplish this task? I just want to know the changes made in an email form.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you want do include in the email? 'Before' and 'after' values for all the changed rows? Does you process insert/update/delete records?

Comment: You can actually ignore my last question. Can you please tell me if I could send the current timestamp of the email minus 1 or 2 hours? What I'm trying to do is send an email with a sql query, that has a where clause that filters for the past 3 hours of changes to the tables.

Comment: Create a mapping to load the results of this query into a flat file or an Excel spreadsheet. Then email the target file as an attachment.